# Adding HTML element from serverside back into clientside

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to have a post go to the backend and get the elements from my ajax post. My backend is Java, which sends an HTML string back to the client-side. I want this string to be displayed as HTML after a certain  tag after the user presses post.

ajax post code:

```
var saveSafetyData = new FormData();
saveSafetyData.append("statusNonUs", statusNonUs.value);
saveSafetyData.append("issuedBy", issuedBy.value);
var entryDate = document.getElementById("entryDate");
saveSafetyData.append("entryDate", entryDate.value);
var effectiveDateNonUs = document.getElementById("effectiveDateNonUs");
saveSafetyData.append("effectiveDateNonUs", effectiveDateNonUs.value);
var expirationDate = document.getElementById("expirationDate");
saveSafetyData.append("expirationDate", expirationDate.value);
saveSafetyData.append("action", "saveNonUsSafetyData");

$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "carrierProfile",
      data: saveSafetyData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             modalSafety.style.display = "none";
             $("#nonUsSafetyForm").trigger("reset");                                
             $("#tabs-3").append("${createNonUsSafety}");
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(errorThrown);
      }
});
```

All the inputs are being pulled from a modal, and once the user hits save, it posts to the backend. So far I have tried `$(#tabs-30).append(htmlString)`, but I get an error on that line that says:

> missing ) after argument list

Here is where the error is and what is shown

```
$("#tabs-3").append("<div id="nonUsSafetyTable" class="carrierViewItem">
```

I cannot seem to figure out what is causing it to stop parsing the string. It stops right after that last `>`

Java code posting back to javascript:

```
if ("saveNonUsSafetyData".equals(action)){
    String statusNonUs = request.getParameter("statusNonUs");
    String issuedBy = request.getParameter("issuedBy");
    session.setAttribute("statusNonUs", statusNonUs);
    String entryDate = request.getParameter("entryDate");
    String effectiveDateNonUs = request.getParameter("effectiveDateNonUs");
    String expirationDate = request.getParameter("expirationDate"); 
    String createNonUsSafety =          "<div id=\"nonUsSafetyTable\" class=\"carrierViewItem\">\n" +
        "                                   <div class=\"divTable\">\n" +
        "                                        <div class=\"divTableBody\">\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"divTableRow\">\n" +
        "                                                <div class=\"divTableCell\">Status: " + statusNonUs + "</div>\n" +
        "                                                <div class=\"divTableCell\">Issued By: " + issuedBy + "</div>\n" +
        "                                                <div class=\"divTableCell\">Entry Date: " + entryDate + "</div>\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"divTableRow\">\n" +
        "                                                <div class=\"divTableCell\">Effective Date: " + effectiveDateNonUs + "</div>\n" +
        "                                                <div class=\"divTableCell\">Expiration Date: "+ expirationDate + "</div>\n" +
        "                                                <div class=\"divTableCell\"></div>\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                        </div>\n" +
        "                                    </div>\n" +
        "                                </div>\n";
    session.setAttribute("createNonUsSafety", createNonUsSafety);
}
```

I am assuming something in my HTML string is causing the end paranthese to not be shown, causing that error.

Comment: Try removing " (double quote) `$("#tabs-3").append(${createNonUsSafety})`

Comment: I did and I get a syntax error: unexpected token "<"

Comment: I think you may need: $("#tabs-3").append(jqXHR.createNonUsSafety);

Comment: @peeto I tried but the html did not show up. Would it require a page refresh to be seen?

Comment: It shouln't. try cosole.log(responseData) and/or console.log(jqXHR) to see if the Java is being sensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing \" (backward slash and double quote in java code) to single quote ('). That should work.

```
"<div id='nonUsSafetyTable' class='carrierViewItem'>\n"
```

Let me know if that worked.

**Suggestion:**
I would say improve your code. Creating html on java side is not a good idea it is always a error prone and hard to debug. 
Instead You should set those property in Java Bean object and then render that back in UI.

Comment: I did this, and set an alert after $("#addNonUsSafety").append("${createNonUsSafety}"). The alert showed my inputs with the HTML string I want. But my table did not show up in the UI. Would it require a page refresh for it to show?

Comment: Trying using  `$("#addNonUsSafety").html("${createNonUsSafety}")` and remove the alert. It should not requires a refresh.

Comment: It still is not showing, I checked my developer console and it was not shown either.

Comment: Now I see in your code you are appending html to "tabs-3" div, so use `$("#tabs-3").html("${createNonUsSafety}");` instead `$("#addNonUsSafety").html("${createNonUsSafety}")`. There is no such div "addNonUsSafety" exist in your code and because of that it is not getting shown.

Comment: I am confused as to what .html() does. I thought it retrieved that elements content? If there is an ID in the parentheses, it will then basically use .innerHTML ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the `$("#tabs-3").html("${createNonUsSafety}");`, and it overwrote what was contained in tabs-3, and it was just whitespace left. Something is working but it is still not showing my HTML string.

Comment: To avoid override you can go with `.append` which you were using earlier.
`$("#tabs-3").append("${createNonUsSafety}");`
.html() replace the existing content with the new content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `\n` while generating HTML string.

*Newline characters are not necessary to render HTML it's just to make it more readable for humans.*

Try dropping `\n` from server side code , it might work

i.e. replace :

```
"<div id=\"nonUsSafetyTable\" class=\"carrierViewItem\">\n"
```

by this :

```
"<div id=\"nonUsSafetyTable\" class=\"carrierViewItem\">"
```

Comment: I seem to still be getting the same error, although all the html code is now showing up. Its not just the first piece of it anymore.

Comment: console.log(responseData) add this in your success call and examine object retruned from post response

Answer (score 0):

change this statement

```
$("#tabs-3").append("${createNonUsSafety}");
```

with

```
$("#tabs-3").html("${createNonUsSafety}");
```